# Tensorflow.compat not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

and getting an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'.
```

I've installed tensorflow=2.8.0, tensorflow-estimator=2.1, tensorflow-gpu=2.8.0 and the python version is 3.9.9. What could be the issue?

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue. Since you have installed `Tensorflow 2.8`, there is no need of `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`, instead can you please try to `import tensorflow as tf`.

Comment: same issue on tensorflow 2.2.0